# Lazy-loading and thread-safe dictionary

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety, lazy-loading, grand-central-dispatch, nsmutabledictionary

I often use this pattern:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) NSMutableDictionary * mutableDictionary;

[...]

- (id)objectForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    id result = self.mutableDictionary[key];

    if (!result)
    {
        result = [...] ; // go and fetch the result;

        self.mutableDictionary[key] = result;
    }

    return result ;
}
```

But I realized recently that it is not thread-safe. I would like to have a similar lazy-loading pattern but which is thread-safe.

What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: `@synchronized(self) { ... }`, maybe? but it is hard to tell, because it is undefined how you mean _go and fetch the result_...

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at this, I have never used `@synchronized`... I have to learn how to use it and it does.

Comment: I am querying a core data database, for instance. Or, I am filtering over an array owned by another class.

Answer (score 0):

I would use NSLock objects. They are easy to use. Just wrap the setter of the mutabledictionary in it.

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) NSMutableDictionary * mutableDictionary;

NSLock *mutexLock = [NSLock new];
[...]

- (id)objectForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    id result = self.mutableDictionary[key];

    if (!result)
    {
        [mutexLock lock];
        result = [...] ; // go and fetch the result;
        self.mutableDictionary[key] = result;
        [mutexLock unlock];
    }

    return result ;
}
```

**Update:** This assumes everything in `//go fetch results` is NOT thread safe.

Comment: I am not and expert with this objects, but I would put the `lock` before the "go and fetch the result"...

Comment: @Colas sure, if that part contains modifying mutable arrays or variables. If they ONLY do a read, you don't need to lock them. The larger your code is in between synchronized or mutex locks, the less use multithreading is. Hence ONLY mutex lock what you know needs to be locked.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. Basically, result will fetch some result depending on `key` and create an array with them. Hence, if two threads enter at the same time this part of the code, the created results might be different and only one will be retained. No?

Comment: @Colas yes. You need to lock the fetch as well. I updated my answer.